# Fetching data using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, jira

part of my job is fetching data from JIRA. Because there is a lot of data I'm fetching data using threads:

```
import concurrent.futures as fs

session = Session(user, password)
total_num_issues = send_request(url, session,
                                    params={**params, **{
                                      "maxResults": "1"
                                    }})["total"]
url = "https://jira_link_for_my_company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3Dsome_project"
page_size = 100
future_list = []
with fs.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as ex:
    for start_at in range(0, total_num_issues + 1, page_size):
        extra_params = {"startAt": start_at, "maxResults": page_size}
        future_list.append(ex.submit(send_request, url, session, {**params, **extra_params}))
    for future in fs.as_completed(future_list):
        issues += future.result()["issues"]
```

In order to fetch data from JIRA you need to be logged in. To avoid logging each time we call `send_request` function I developed [cookie based authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/cookie-based-authentication/). The way it's working is as follow:

- We log into JIRA once and obtain cookie (it's like checking the box "Remember me")
- As long as we have the cookie and it did not expire (it expires after 5 mins), we do not need to log into JIRA

Thanks to that instead of having ~10k loggins each task, I have ~30 logins, and here is my problem that I do not understand: for some reason for some tasks that last > 5 mins the number of logins is above 30 while it should 2 if it took ~7 mins (2 times we had to get two cookies - 1 for first time, and second after 5 mins). The reason of that as I assume is that each thread does not "see" that other thread has already obtained new cookie for session after 1st cookie expires and because of that after 5 mins we do not log once to set up new session, but each thread do it by itself (30 times).

Previously I was not using `class object` and instead I was just using semiglobal variable with a cookie and it's generation time but it was not working so I developed `Session` class because I though maybe as each thread works on same object they will "notice", that the new cookie has been already obtained and `session.cookie_time` has been restarted, but still it is not working (each thread creates session for itself)

```
def send_request(url, session, params={}):
  headers = {
  "cookie" : session.get_cookie(),
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  }
  for attr_item in params.items():
  # attribute item is a tuple of name and value pair of the attribute
      url = f"{url}&{attr_item[0]}={attr_item[1]}"
  response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
  return json.loads(response.text)
```

```
class Session:
  def __init__(self, user, password):
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    # session_url is a static (same for all projects) link to JIRA,
    # #used for signing in and obtaining cookie of the session
    self.session_url = "https://jira_link_for_my_company.com/rest/auth/1/session"
    # session_time is a time in second after which we should set a new session (obtain new cookie)
    self.session_time = 300 
    self.cookie_time = None
    self.cookie = None
    
    self.set_session()
  
  def set_session(self):
    auth_string = base64.b64encode(str.encode(f"{self.user}:{self.password}"))
    headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic %s" % str(auth_string)[2:-1],
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.get(url=self.session_url, headers=headers)
    self.cookie = response.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(';')[0]
    self.cookie_time = time.time()
  
  def get_cookie(self):
    if time.time() - self.cookie_time > self.session_time:
      self.set_session()
    return self.cookie
```

Comment: What about trying personal access token with Bearer authentication?

Comment: O, I haven't heared about it before. I will give it a try